# DateTime Object to string

Tags: php, datetime, time

When I pull birthday date from the Facebook SKD I get DateTime Object, and I have been struggling convert it to string.

```
print_r($birthday);
```

> DateTime Object ( [date] => 1978-03-09 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )

But when i try to create another DateTime Object and convert it over to string

```
$date = new DateTime($birthday->date);
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I get

> Undefined prperty: DateTime::$date

And when I

```
$date = new DateTime($birthday['date']);
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

> Cannot use object of type DateTime as array

Comment: `$birthday` is already a `DateTime` object, so `$birthday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why try and create a new DateTime object use the one you have and just format the output

```
echo $birthday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```